# Long query put into a CI function become not work

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Does anyone can help me,I have mysql query and i have test it in phpmyadmin:

```
select items.name, items.category, items.supplier_id, items.item_number, 
items.product_id, items.description, items.size, items.tax_included, 
items.cost_price, if(items_tier_prices.unit_price is not null, 
items_tier_prices.unit_price,items.unit_price) as unit_price, 
items.promo_price, items.start_date, items.end_date, items.reorder_level, 
items.item_id, items.allow_alt_description, items.is_serialized, 
items.image_id, items.override_default_tax, items.is_service, items.deleted 

from items, item_kit_items_formula
left join items_tier_prices
on items_tier_prices.item_id=item_kit_items_formula.item_id
left join price_tiers
on price_tiers.id=items_tier_prices.tier_id

where item_kit_items_formula.item_id=items.item_id
and item_kit_items_formula.item_kit_id=1
and (price_tiers.name is null or price_tiers.name like '%Jendela Kaca Mati Single%')
```

Query above display results just like i want. But when i put into a model function (that just work before with simple query), program dont works.

```
function get_info3($item_id)
{

    $this->db->select('items.name, items.category, items.supplier_id, items.item_number, items.product_id, items.description, items.size, items.tax_included, items.cost_price, if(items_tier_prices.unit_price is not null, items_tier_prices.unit_price,items.unit_price) as unit_price, items.promo_price, items.start_date, items.end_date, items.reorder_level, items.item_id, items.allow_alt_description, items.is_serialized, items.image_id, items.override_default_tax, items.is_service, items.deleted '); 
    $this->db->from('items, item_kit_items_formula');
    $this->db->join('items_tier_prices','items_tier_prices.item_id=item_kit_items_formula.item_id','left');
    $this->db->join('price_tiers','price_tiers.id=items_tier_prices.tier_id','left');
    $this->db->where('item_kit_items_formula.item_id=items.item_id');

    $this->db->where('item_id',$item_id);
    $this->db->where('(price_tiers.name IS NULL or price_tiers.name like "%jendela kaca mati single%"');


     $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()==1)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
    else
    {
        $item_obj=new stdClass();

        $fields = $this->db->list_fields('items');

        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $item_obj->$field='';
        }

        return $item_obj;
    }
}
```

my previous code that work is:
    function get_info($item_id)
    {

```
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->where('item_id',$item_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows()==1)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
    else
    {
        //Get empty base parent object, as $item_id is NOT an item
        $item_obj=new stdClass();

        //Get all the fields from items table
        $fields = $this->db->list_fields('items');

        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $item_obj->$field='';
        }

        return $item_obj;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to look at this CI function? what i have done wrong?
 Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I edited in my code,
try this:

```
function get_info3($item_id)
{

$sql_query = "select items.name, items.category, items.supplier_id, items.item_number, 
items.product_id, items.description, items.size, items.tax_included, 
items.cost_price, if(items_tier_prices.unit_price is not null, 
items_tier_prices.unit_price,items.unit_price) as unit_price, 
items.promo_price, items.start_date, items.end_date, items.reorder_level, 
items.item_id, items.allow_alt_description, items.is_serialized, 
items.image_id, items.override_default_tax, items.is_service, items.deleted 
from items, item_kit_items_formula
left join items_tier_prices
on items_tier_prices.item_id=item_kit_items_formula.item_id
left join price_tiers
on price_tiers.id=items_tier_prices.tier_id
where item_kit_items_formula.item_id=items.item_id
and item_kit_items_formula.item_kit_id=1
and (price_tiers.name is null or price_tiers.name like '%Jendela Kaca Mati Single%')";


 $query = $this->db->query($sql_query);

if($query->num_rows()==1)
{
    return $query->row();
}
else
{
    $item_obj=new stdClass();

    $fields = $this->db->list_fields('items');

    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        $item_obj->$field='';
    }

    return $item_obj;
}
```

}

Comment: hi Yash thanks for the reply i have try yours but still not working. can u help me how to alert / echo the whole query string?

Comment: you can use `echo $this->db->last_query();` to see the last executed query.

Comment: we can not use two tables in single `from()` in codeigniter.

Comment: hmm.. but it still not working,pls see my edited Question

Comment: you can execute your manual sql code in codeigniter using `$this->db->query()` function.

Comment: where should i put $this->db->query() ?

Comment: remove all db statement and simply use `$query = $this->db->query('your select query');`

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_info3($item_id)
{

  $this->db->select('i.*,i_t_p.*,i_k_i_f.*,pt.*,if(i_t_p.unit_price is not null, i_t_p.unit_price,i.unit_price) as unit_price'); 
  $this->db->from('items as i');
  $this->db->join('items_tier_prices as i_t_p','i_t_p.item_id=i_k_i_f.item_id','left');
  $this->db->join('price_tiers as pt','pt.id=i_t_p.tier_id','left');
  $this->db->where('i_k_i_f.item_id=i.item_id');

  $this->db->where('i.item_id',$item_id);
  $this->db->where('(pt.name IS NULL or pt.name like "%jendela kaca mati single%"');



}
```

you have to join table , i try to reduce your code but i don't know this **item_kit_items_formula** table is where to join with which id so you have to join this too ..hope this would help ..